# App inventor 2 MockingApp

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to create an app in MIT App Inventor that allows me to type a sentence or a word into the text box and when I click the submit button, the result will show a mocked version of that.

For example, if I type in "hello there sir," it will take each separate letter and randomize it to have capital lettering or lowercase lettering. So it could have a result like "hElLo tHErE sIr."

I assume the blocks would be made so that it would take each separate letter have a probability of 50% and capitalize the letter 50% of the time. But I do not know how to do that.

[This is what i have so far, but the label turned up blank:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT1px.png) 
[image]

Comment: is there a specific part of this you are looking for help with or having trouble with?

Comment: you forgot to call the mock procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attaching the blocks as image. The function splits the original text into individual letters, and randomly upcases or downcases them.

[Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUiRd.png)
[image]

Comment: I understand the above a little bit but I'm not sure how to get the "get text" block or the "text" block after "mock." Also, I did this but I am not sure what to link for the result. Do I say, "when button pressed, set label to get mock text result" or something else?